# How to get root_url into interpolation inside rails model concerns

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to add `root_url` to "#{url}#{uuid}", but what I have results to another path i.e. `http://localhost:3000/links/15/yeyb7ebdbee` instead of `http://localhost:3000/yeyb7ebdbee`. How do I go about concatenating `root_url` to uuid in model concerns.

Here is what I have done below:

## app/models/concerns/linkable.rb

```
module Linkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save :create_short_url
    delegate :url_helpers, to: "Rails.application.routes"
    alias :h :url_helpers
  end

  def url
    h.send :"#{route}_url", parameterize
  end

  def route
    # self.class.name.parameterize
    self.model_name.param_key
  end

  def parameterize
    self.id
  end

  protected

  def create_short_url
    update_column :short_url, "#{url}#{uuid}"
  end
end
```

## initializers/host.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it, there is no need to parameterize `model_name` because calling `:root_url` will always return lowercase and you do not need `id` since its the `root_url` you need. By calling `self.model_name.param_key` or `self.class.name.parameterize`, the response will result to `http://localhost:3000/links/15`

Just pass in the `:root_url` symbol directly in your `def url; end` function as seen below and remove these two methods `def route; end` and `def parameterize; end` and you will be fine:

```
def url
  h.send :root_url
end
```

So to be explicit, what you will not have is:

## app/models/concerns/linkable.rb

```
module Linkable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    after_save :create_short_url
    delegate :url_helpers, to: "Rails.application.routes"
    alias :h :url_helpers
  end

  def url
    h.send :root_url
  end

  protected

  def create_short_url
    update_column :short_url, "#{url}#{uuid}"
  end
end
```

## initializers/host.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host] = 'localhost:3000'
```